# Hibernate 3.6 customize the setter of one to many mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a simple `@OneToMany` mapping:

```
public class Member(){
    ....
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="member", orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<User> users;

    @Transient
    private User firstUser;
    ...

    public setUsers(List<User> users){
      //if(users.size() > 0) this.firstUser = users.get(0);
      this.users = users;
    }

}

public class User(){
    .....
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private Member member;
}
```

Here I'd like to set `this.firstUser = users.get(0)` if the mapped users length is greater than 0. However it doesn't work if I put the code directly into the `setter` method like the commented line in `Member`, for example, I read a member object which `users` size is 5, then I tried to print `firstUser`, `firstUser` is still null, expected result should be `users.get(0)`.

Any idea?

Comment: Well why do you need a separate firstUser when you can just get the first user from the list?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. With _"However it doesn't work as I put the code directly into the setter method"_, do you really mean "However it doesn't work __if__ I put the code directly into the setter method"? Also, how doesn't it work? What happens?

Comment: @user2710256 we don't want to change the frontend code, `firstUser` is required for the frontend.

Comment: @Magnilex in fact I haven't tried the serialization stuff yet, I found the `firstUser` was null via debugging, which means it hadn't been serialized, right?

Comment: @Magnilex so in that case, this salutation is a bad approach for solving the problem without changing the frontend code right?

Comment: @Magnilex The field will still be serialized, this annotation is for JPA/Hibernate only. To disable serialization, the field would need to be declared with the transient keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the setter is actually called ? By default, if your *@Id* or *@EmbeddedId* are on a field, then the state is accessed via the field and setters are not called. If that's the case, you can use `@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)` on the relation to force Hibernate to use the setter instead of reflection :

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="member", orphanRemoval=true)
@Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
private List<User> users;
```

Anyway, in your case it's probably a bad idea to do it this way. Do you really need the field ? You should be able to work with this :

```
public User getFirstUser()
{
    return users != null && !users.isEmpty() ? users.get(0) : null;
}
```

Comment: No, it was not called, but even I put @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY) to `users` it still never been called. the second approach you suggested is better, but we also have to modify the frontend code right? in frontend they read the property from JSON objects where there won't be a `getFirstUser` method.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
public class Member(){
    ....
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="member", orphanRemoval=true)
    private List<User> users;

    @Transient
    private User firstUser;
    ...

    public setUser(List<User> users){
      if(users.size() > 0) this.firstUser = users.get(0);
      this.users = users;
    }

    @PostLoad
    public void setTransientUser() {
        this.setUsers(this.users);
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using JPA EntityManager ?

Comment: No, I'm using SessionFactory based configuration.

Comment: With SessionFactory you can use hibernate interceptors/events. You can find more information at: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html#objectstate-events